# NavigationController in swift leads to a black screen

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I'm trying to use a navigation controller for an identification process in my swift code but each time I click on a button that leads to it, it shows the following black screen:

[image: Black screen on IOS simulator]

Here is my storyboard if this can helps, there is no warning and no error in the code (using a drag and drop segue or a programmatically one leads to the same black screen)

[image: My Storyboard with segues]

Comment: Please post code, not images, will be easier for everyone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably the `segue` you picked: mode & transition.

Are you certain you only have a single `segue`? It is possible to have overlapping segues, which do not show up clearly in Interface Builder.

**Edit**

> Is there a way we can see all our segues?

1. Open the *Storyboard* in its new window
2. Show Document Outline (leftmost pane)
3. Show Attribute Inspector (rightmost pane)
4. Select each View Controller Scene in the Document Outline. The `Segues` are listed at the bottom. You can inspect **Identifier** and **Segue** in the Attribute Inspector.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I don't know, now I have this warning : "segues initiated directly from view controllers must have an identifier", but when I click on it it doesn't highlight any segue so is there a way we can see all our segues ? (like the left panel sounds to show only the ones we see on the storyboard)

Comment: Well I've done this, no segue but still this unsupported configuration warning. The problem is I don't know where it is, maybe it is hidden ?

Comment: I was haping your solution to work but it hasn't. So I have created a new project from scratch without code, just segues (here is the storyboard : http://i.imgur.com/cozg0Kz.png ) with names. So maybe (or certainly), I am doing something wrong and maybe my navigation controller doesn't have any  children view (actually, I drag a segue from the leftmost icon at the top of the middle view to my next controller). Just running the navigation controller with the predefined table view works, so can we add view controller to navigationcontroller (I think so, but I am trying to fix this problem)

Comment: Sounds, I was doing the wrong way (drag a nav controller, delete the table view, add a new View controller and make the segue), but now if I create a view, and then I embed it in a navigation controller it sounds it works ! Anyway, thanks a lot for your help, this definitely helps me !

Answer (score 0):

Sounds, I was doing the wrong way (drag a nav controller, delete the table view, add a new View controller and make the segue), but now if I create a view, and then I embed it in a navigation controller it sounds it works ! Anyway, thanks a lot for your help, this definitely helps me !

Answer (score 0):

I got this when I assigned a custom view to `self.view` in `viewDidLoad:`.

`self.view = self.mapView`

Adding mapView as a subview of `self.view` solved this.

Answer (score 0):

[I see you've created a custom ViewController, are you sure it's a subclass of ViewController?

You can see which subclass is it off after the ":" in the class declaration! 
[image]